# Making a gridview inside of an scrollview, that is the size of the screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a gridview with square elements inside of it that scrolls. I found some code in the documentation and some on the internet and I managed to get something working.

```
class ElementPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            icon = ElementIcon(str(i), "cat.png", size_hint_y=None)
            icon.height = icon.width
            layout.add_widget(icon)
        scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(scrollview)
```

Running this I get a scrolling grid of ElementIcon that I can scroll, but its always 400x400 pixels in size, regardless of window size. Is there a way to make it the size of the window (actually, the parent widget), or better yet is there a way to set what percentage of the size I want it to be?

I tried messing with the code, especially this line:

```
scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
```

But with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me as long as you don't specify any sizing for the `ScrollView`.

Change this:

```
scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
```

...to this:

```
scrollview = ScrollView()
```

To keep the buttons square, we can use `GridLayout`'s `row_default_height`:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, row_force_default=True)
layout.bind(width=lambda *_: setattr(layout, 'row_default_height', 
        (layout.width - (layout.spacing[0] * (layout.cols - 1))) / layout.cols))
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

Comment: This works, but now the elements of GridView aren't square. The only reason they were square in the first place is because ScrollView was square. Is there any way to make the square regardless of ScrollView?

Comment: I've added a method to keep the buttons square.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing:

> size=(400,400)

to

> size=(min(root.width, root.height),min(root.width, root.height))